# Find places using Google Maps and GPS

Tags: android, gps, maps

demkeyI'm trying to create an google maps request finding the nearest pharmacies or hospitals near my location but I'm facing some problems.

The code is :

```
public class MostrarFarmaciasHospitales extends Activity {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            comprobarGPSActivado(locationManager);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();



            farmaciasHospitalesCercanos();
        }


    private void comprobarGPSActivado(LocationManager locationManager) {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("El GPS está desactivado. ¿Quiere activarlo? ")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Sí.",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }

    public void farmaciasHospitalesCercanos() {

        String[] farmaciasHopsitales = {"Farmacias cercanas a mí" , "Hospitales a mi alrededor"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Qué quiere buscar?")
                .setItems(farmaciasHopsitales, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        switch (which){
                            case 0: //Farmacias
                                //String urlPH = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=5000&types=farmacia&sensor=false&key=demkey";
                                String urlPH = ("https://www.google.es/maps/search/farmacia/@"+latitude+","+longitude);
                                Intent intentPH = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlPH));
                                intentPH.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                                startActivity(intentPH);
                                MostrarFarmaciasHospitales.this.finish();
                                break;

                            case 1://Hospitales
                                String urlH = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location="+latitude+","+longitude+"&radius=5000&types=hospital&sensor=false&key=demkey";
                                Intent intentH = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlH));
                                intentH.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                                startActivity(intentH);
                                MostrarFarmaciasHospitales.this.finish();
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

AS you can see, I've tried using the simply google maps request and also the radar search. None of them is working as it is supposed to.

If I use the normal google request, the search is correctly done but not where I am, just in a random place in the country. And also if I use this option, when the GPS is enabled in the device, the app is crashing. As you can see I have a method asking the user to enable the GPS but it never comes out, like the method is never reached.

If I use the radar search, It centers the camera in the good location, where I am, but there is no text typed in the search bar.

How could I solve it? Seems like the radar search is the way, but I dont know why this is failing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day.Please refer to this links they defiantly will help you and get you started.Both of links have source code available to download so you don't need to make it hard for you if you feel like to:)

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc

Second

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnEjFjQPNHM